# Refactor for loops into function

Tags: java, function, for-loop

I've got this piece of java code:

```
int maxDigit = 4;
for(int a = 0; a <= maxDigit; a++)
{
  for(int b = 0; b <= maxDigit; b++)
  {
    if(b != a){
      for(int c = 0; c <= maxDigit; c++)
      {
        if(c != a && c != b)
        {
          for(int d = 0; d <= maxDigit; d++)
          {
            if(d != a && d != b && d != c)
            {
              for(int e = 0; e <= maxDigit; e++)
              {
                if(e != a && e != b && e != c && e != d)
                {
                  String temp = a + "" + b + "" + c + "" + d + "" + e;
                  System.out.println(temp);
                  permutations.add(Integer.parseInt(temp));
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can you transform this piece of code into a function?

The purpose is to generate permutations of the digits 0 to 9 and here in the code above it is from 0 to 4. And it seems easy to put it in a function but i couldn't find it immediately.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but... creating ints by concatenating strings and then parsing the result? That's about the least efficient way I can think of. Try "permutations.add(a*10000 + b*1000 + c*100 + d*10 + e)" instead.

Answer (score 4):

This is a variant of the classic problem of getting [all permutations of a string](https://web.archive.org/web/20091027075904/http://geocities.com/oosterwal/computer/combinations.html).

The induction your professor wants you to make is that this problem lends itself well to a solution that uses **recursion**.

The basic algorithm for the permutations of string `s` is as follows:

1. Select the first item in `s`.
2. Get all permutations of the other items in `s` (except the item selected).
3. Prepend selected item to each permutation from step 2.
4. Repeat for the next character of `s`.

Here's an efficient solution using the [Functional Java](https://www.functionaljava.org/) library.

Import these...

```
import fj.F;
import fj.P2;
import fj.P1;
import fj.data.Stream;
import static fj.data.Stream.nil;
import static fj.data.Stream.cons;
import static fj.data.Stream.range;
import static fj.data.Enumerator.charEnumerator;
import static fj.data.Show.streamShow;
import static fj.data.Show.charShow;
import static fj.P2.map2_;
```

A recursive function to find permutations:

```
public Stream<Stream<Character>> permutations(final Stream<Character> s) {
  return selections(s).bind(
    new F<P2<Character, Stream<Character>>, Stream<Stream<Character>>>() {
      public Stream<Stream<Character>>()
        f(final P2<Character, Stream<Character>> ys) {
          return permutations(ys._2()).bind(cons(ys._1()));
        }
      });
}
```

A recursive function to select each element in turn:

```
public Stream<P2<Character, Stream<Character>>>
selections(final Stream<Character> s) {
  if (xs.isEmpty())
    return nil();
  else {
    final char x = xs.head();
    final Stream<Character> xs = s.tail()._1();
    return cons(P.p(x, xs),
      new P1<Stream<P2<Character, Stream<Character>>>>() {
        public Stream<P2<Character, Stream<Character>>> _1() { 
          return selections(xs).map(map2_().f(cons(x))));
        }
      });
  }
}
```

and then, to get all permutations of characters '0' through '9':

```
Show<Stream<Character>> s = streamShow(charShow);
for (Stream<Character> ps : permutations(range(charEnumerator, '0', '9'))) {
  System.out.println(s.showS(ps));
}
```

**EDIT**: This is actually a great use case for [comonads](https://web.archive.org/web/20210514170237/https://planetmath.org/comonad). Using the latest trunk head of Functional Java, you can do this with the Zipper comonad, like so:

```
public static Stream<Stream<Character>> perms(Stream<Character> s) {
  Stream<Stream<Character>> r = single(Stream.<Character>nil());
  for (final Zipper<Character> z : fromStream(s))
    r = join(z.cobind(
      new F<Zipper<Character>, Stream<Stream<Character>>>() {
        public Stream<Stream<Character>> f(final Zipper<Character> zp) {
          return perms(zp.lefts().reverse().append(zp.rights())).map(compose(
            Stream.<Character>cons().f(zp.focus()),
              P.<Stream<Character>>p1()));
        }
      }).toStream());
  return r;
}
```

Comment: It looks like Functional Java could really use type inference... it's hard for me to see the actual operations under all that <Zipper<Character>, Stream<Stream<Character>>.

Answer (score 1):

Fill the holes:

```
int[] indexes = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
addPermutations(maxDigit, indexes, 0, permutations);


void addPermutations(int max, int[] indexes, int currentIndex, List<Integer> permutations) {
    if (currentIndex == indexes.length) {
        // terminal case
        String temp = ...;
        System.out.println(temp);
        permutations.add(Integer.parseInt(temp));
    } else {
        // recursive case
        for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
            if (... != i) {
                indexes[currentIndex] = i;
                addPermutations(max, indexes, currentIndex+1, permutations);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No code, but an algorithm should be as follows.

Suppose you want all permutations of 5 digits from 0 to 7. To do that:

- Calculate `j =` decimal value of base-7 value of 100000 (1 + 5 zeroes)
- Loop `for i = 0; i < j; ++i`, converting each `i` to base-7 system, optionally prepending with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an N-ary tree, with 4 branches at each point, recursively navigate the tree and step over branches where that node's digit had already been seen?